# how do I mock super methods in subclass test?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a superclass

```
public class superAuthClass {
    public boolean authorize(String id) {
      //does some check, returns a boolean
   }
}
```

I have a sublcass which extends the superAuthClass

```
public class subAuthClass extends superAuthClass {
  public boolean authorize (String id1) {
       
 if (super.authorize(id1)) {
      return true;
}
//does some logic to figure out the fallback id2
 else {
      if (super.authorize(id2))
          return true;
}
return false;
}
```

How do I mock super.authorize while testing subclass implementation ?

Comment: You don't. You're testing that the subclass Does The Right Thing, however it does that. Mock whatever it's using to make that first `authorize` check if the purpose of the test is to test fallback.

Comment: Updated the question, @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 1):

If you can, consider using composition rather than inheritance. Instead of inheriting from `SuperAuthClass` you could have an `Authorizer` interface which is implemented by your `SuperAuthClass`, and a `DelegatingAuthorizer` that is composed from another `Authorizer`:

```
interface Authorizer {
  boolean authorize(String id);
}

class SuperAuthClass implements Authorizer {
  ...
}

class DelegatingAuthorizer implements Authorizer {
  private Authorizer delegate;

  public boolean authorize(String id) {
    if (delegate.authorize(id)) {
      return true;
    }
    String id2 = ...;
    return delegate.authorize(id2);
  }
}
```

Client code would be refactored to understand `Authorizer`s, and not have any knowledge of `SuperAuthClass`.

This approach makes testing much easier: it's very easy to mock an interface when you are testing the clients of `Authorizer`, and it makes testing the `DelegatingAuthorizer` simple.

This design also means your `DelegatingAuthorizer` is not tied to only `SuperAuthClass` - it can be used with any `Authorizer`. This will make your code more maintainable over time. With inheritence, one day you'll discover that you need another type of `SuperAuthClass` - maybe you want to support LDAP, for example - and then your `SubAuthClass` will be a burden.

I realize this does not directly answer your question, but hopefully you can tinker with your design to make testing easier.